# Segmentation fault when using composer

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- PHP Version: 7.4.22

I am trying to install a package with `composer`. But it caused a Segmentation Fault:

```sh
root@micro7:/www/wwwroot/micro7.ml# composer require laravel/breeze
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The problem also appeared when creating project with `composer`:

```sh
root@micro7:~# composer create-project laravel/laravel micro7.ml
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./micro7.ml"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I used `gdb` to get the stack trace of the dumped core, it looked like this:

```sh
root@micro7:~# gdb php core
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from php...
[New LWP 583799]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `php /usr/bin/composer create-project laravel/laravel micro7.ml'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fec2b356e00 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fec2b356e00 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
#1  0x00007fec2c1ecf6c in SSL_CTX_new () from /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
#2  0x00007fec2bf0ab3c in ossl_connect_step1 () from /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
#3  0x00007fec2bf0c4ff in ossl_connect_common () from /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
#4  0x00007fec2bf0d47c in Curl_ssl_connect_nonblocking () from /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
#5  0x00007fec2bed2996 in https_connecting () from /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
#6  0x00007fec2bed4383 in Curl_http_connect () from /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
#7  0x00007fec2bee734d in multi_runsingle () from /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
#8  0x00007fec2bee84b1 in curl_multi_perform () from /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
#9  0x000055bdd4a2c339 in zif_curl_multi_exec ()
#10 0x000055bdd5166c3d in execute_ex ()
#11 0x000055bdd517e815 in zend_execute ()
#12 0x000055bdd4fce45b in zend_execute_scripts ()
#13 0x000055bdd4f05a84 in php_execute_script ()
#14 0x000055bdd51815df in do_cli ()
#15 0x000055bdd5182a24 in main ()
```

If you look at the first line of the output of the `bt`, you'll find that the Segmentation Fault maybe caused when establishing a SSL connection to the server of packagist.

I tried to reinstall composer, switch to the super user, reboot the server, even reinstalling the OS, but the problem still persist!

Comment: Can you share more details? Does `composer diagnose` print any warning?